# Conditional link a library on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to link a library conditionally (I have this library for iOS device, but I don't have it for Simulator). I am using Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1.

I read a question (and couple similar ones): [iOS conditional link static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298076/ios-conditional-link-static-library)

**-weak_library linker flag**

I tried ry to build the project with following flags:

```
-weak_library LibraryNameWithPath
```

However it gives me an error:

```
ld: file not found: LibraryNameWithPath
```

**-weak-l linker flag**

I tried to build it with following flags:

```
-weak-lShortLibraryName
```

And got the same results :

```
ld: library not found for -lShortLibraryName
```

**Thoughts**

Why the heck, does it check for library existence, if it is explicitly marked to be a weak link?

Is there a way to do conditional linking in build time (vs runtime usage of dlopen, dlclose and friends)?

Comment: Is this what you want?  [Conditional Link Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298076/ios-conditional-link-static-library)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: The answer in there is "use -weak_library", which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

I actually haven't tried to do this with build flags directly, but I've done it with the Xcode GUI settings.  Select your build **Target**, then **Build Phases**, and then choose to add your static library to the list of binaries to link.

However, select **Optional** (which is not the default) from the Required/Optional menu on the right.

[image]

Since this is a *static* library you're talking about, I think you'd then need to put some preprocessor guards in your code, to disable use of the library in the simulator:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
   NSLog(@"do nothing here!");
#else
   HelloLibrary* hl = [[HelloLibrary alloc] init];
   NSString* result = [hl helloLibraryFoo];
#endif
```

I did **nothing** else to make this work (no other **Build Settings** were modified).

When building for the simulator, I just get this warning:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/me/Desktop/code/MyAppName/libHelloLibrary.a, file was built for
>   archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386):
>   /Users/me/Desktop/code/MyAppName/libHelloLibrary.a

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to do this for `CoreAudioKit` which is necessary for MIDI over Bluetooth, but not available in the simulator. Changing the framework to "optional" and using an `#if` in the code around the imports doesn't help remove the `library not found` message. Removing the framework entirely works. I'm kind of stumped.

Comment: @Yar, I think the original question was for static libraries, but `CoreAudioKit` is a (dynamic) framework, so your issue is a little different. Can you ask a new question? Feel free to ping me by posting a link to the new question in the comments here.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Question is here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31574430/8047 and any help appreciated!